# Finding root of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, exponential-function, roots, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find the number of real root in the equation

### $2\cos \left ( \frac{x^{2}+x}{6} \right )=2^{x}+2^{-x}$

I got one  root ,i.e.   $\cos \left ( \frac{x^{2}+x}{6} \right )$

Is it correct??

Comment: No, it's not correct. The one and only zero of this equation is hinted in the first very nice answer below.

Comment: Another one: [How to solve this equation $2\cos(\frac {x^2+x}{6})=2^x+2^{-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/770306/42969).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121453/number-of-real-roots-of-2-cos-left-fracx2x6-right-2x2-x

Comment: $\cos \left ( \frac{x^{2}+x}{6} \right )$ is not a root, it is an expression depending on $x$. A root must be a number.

Comment: $\dfrac{2^x+2^{-x}}2=\cosh(x\log2)\ge1$ and $\text{arcosh}(1)=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$2^x + 2^{-x} \geq 2$ by AM-GM, and $2\cos(\frac{x^2+x}{6})\leq 2$

Comment: yes I got it, what is AM-GM??

Comment: AM-GM is the inequality between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean for non-negative reals - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM 
$$2\cos \left ( \frac{x^{2}+x}{6} \right )=2^{x}+2^{-x}\geq2\sqrt{2^x\cdot2^{-x}}=2.$$
The equality occurs for $2^x=2^{-x},$ which gives $x=0$.

But, $$2\cos \left ( \frac{x^{2}+x}{6} \right )\geq2$$ gives 
$$2\cos \left ( \frac{x^{2}+x}{6} \right )=2,$$ which says that it's ewnough to check that $0$ is indeed the root.

Can you end it now?